# How to filter data in custom grid?

Tags: magento-1.9, collection-filtering

I am using grid serialization in my custom module grid.

I want to filter data using `student_ids`.

I have current student id.

In database student_ids save multiple student id for Ex. `1,2,3`.

Now i want to filter grid current student id exists in student_ids.

I am trying this

```
$currentStudentId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $collection = Mage::getModel('example/data')->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('student_ids',array('like' => '%,'.$currentStudentId));
```

but using this i can't get proper data because string is like this `1,2,3` here so many possibility so i can't use this please give me solution

**[EDIT]**

[image]

Comment: can you please show the database table data in screenshot.

Comment: you can use array('in' => array(1,2,3)) instead of array('like' => '%,'.$currentStudentId)

Comment: not possible $currentStudentId is single value like 1 or 2 or 3. student_ids is 1,2,3 and check my update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [finset sql cluse](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php)

```
$currentStudentId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $collection = Mage::getModel('example/data')->getCollection()
         ->addFieldToFilter('student_ids',array("finset"=>$currentStudentId);
```

basically this clause use in magento when we have multiple selection in any attribute

hope it will work for you.